# ASP.NET MVC 2 - Property validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new to MVC and have a question regarding validation. Is there a way to dynamically set the Error Message?

For example, how could I achieve the following (ignore the hardcoded 50, this could come from the Web.config or specific to the current logged).

```
[MetadataType(typeof(DocumentValidation))]
public partial class Document
{
    public class DocumentValidation
    {
        private const int MaxLength = 50;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Document Title is required")]
        [StringLength(MaxLength, ErrorMessage = "Must be under " + MaxLength.ToString() + " characters")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

}

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [IDataErrorInfo](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validating-with-the-idataerrorinfo-interface--cs) and this question I asked about [IDataErrorInfo vs. DataAnnotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103770/dataannotations-vs-idataerrorinfo).

Comment: Thanks you've certainly pointed me in the right direction. I did try awarding the bounty but it's saying I have to wait 23hours.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with dynamic attributes but involves some trickery:

[Dynamic Attributes in C#](http://geekswithblogs.net/abhijeetp/archive/2009/01/10/dynamic-attributes-in-c.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Depending how dynamically you're trying to change ErrorMessage. This might be one solution to your problem: [haacked.com - Localizing ASP.NET MVC Validation](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/12/localizing-aspnetmvc-validation.aspx)

It's a good guide to get localized error message from the resources.´

Comment: Well I'm trying to set the StringLength ErrorMessage to be a variable string rather than a constant string. The above example doesn't compile with the error: 

An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.

I simply want to be able to give custom error messages depending on the circumstance.